# Executing code related to the specific contact form the user is sending

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm quite new to Wordpress, so please forgive me and correct any mistake I'm making, I'm willing to learn and improve :)

I set up multiple contact forms for applying to fitness courses. People need to fill them, and I get an email with their written data.

What I'm trying to do now is execute some PHP code that writes data into a MySQL database whenever the user correctly fills and sends a contact form.

I also need every contact form to have a unique code "attached" to it, because the PHP code needs this code to write the data inside the database. (simply put, every course has its unique code that i need to write in the database along with the user's data).

So far as I understand, I need to use `add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_function' );` in a snippet inside functions.php. What I'm trying to achieve now is to attach this code to every contact form (but it mustn't be visible to users) so that my php snippet reads this code and correctly edits the database.

Any clue on where to look? I don't need the code written, just some ideas!

Thank you in advance, have a nice day everybody.

EDIT: I found out there are "hidden fields" in CF7. So, i added these to my test contact form:

```
[hidden idcorso "6"]
[hidden idgruppo "0"]
```

Then i'm using this snippet, but it doesn't work:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'process_contact_form_data' );

function process_contact_form_data( $contact_data ){

$idcorso = $contact_data->posted_data["idcorso"];
$idgruppo = $contact_data->posted_data["idgruppo"];

if (is_user_logged_in()) {

    $idutente = get_current_user_id();
    $data = current_time('d-m-Y - g:i');
    $stato = 1;
    $wpdb->insert("fis_iscrizioni_2018", array('id_utente' => $idutente, 'id_corso' => $idcorso, 'data' => $data, 'stato' => $stato, 'id_gruppo' => $idgruppo) );              
}
}
```

Any clue?